# no visible @interface for 'UIAPPLICATION.. local notification tutorial failing

Tags: iphone

just learning iPhone and I'm getting the following error

```
    [app scheduledLocalNotifications:notification];
```

no visible @interface for uiapplication declares the selector schedulelocalnotifications

can someone please help me out.  I'm sure its something simple I am just not realizing as this is my first tutorial

thanks

```
-(IBAction)createNotification{

NSLog(@"createNotification");

NSString *dateString = dateTextField.text;
NSString *textString = textTextField.text;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-18000]];

NSDate *alertTime = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notification) {
    notification.fireDate = alertTime;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
    notification.alertBody = textString;

    [app scheduledLocalNotifications:notification];
    [app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**scheduledLocalNotifications is property.**

> This property holds an array of UILocalNotification instances
>   representing the current scheduled local notifications. You can set or
>   reset the local notifications in the array as well as access them.

read a documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

change to alike below code.

```
NSMutableArray *notifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[notifications addObject:notification];
app.scheduledLocalNotifications = notifications;
//Equivalent: [app setScheduledLocalNotifications:notifications];
```

Comment: so I'm using a simulator... and the notification is only showing a banner... how can I change it to an alert?

Comment: it wont let me vote up your answer... says I need 15 reputation.  anything I can do to mark as you solved problem?.... duh,, never mind.. got it